# Listview with custom columns layout nested LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

Am trying to make a restaurant menu that have the following layout . item field and description field under it price amount to the right of the item . i have tried everything from using list-view for each of the row and having the list-view that have the item and description set to 2 items layout but i had a problem with keeping the other list-views synchronized .

now i tried having a list-view layout as my main layout and adding a horizontal linear-layout with the text-views added to it with equal weights. as for the first column that should have 2 items i used a verical linear-layout and added the text-views to it

what i want is to set the vertical linear-layout weight to lets say 3 and the rest of the items to 1 . and inside the vertical linear-layout i want to set the text-views to fill the width of but not exceed to other other columns and the height to warp content since am loading description of the item form the db which is quite a few lines .

what i tried so far is the following this is only the row layout that am adding to the list-layout. the picture below shows the problem with the list.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1_"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2_"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Layout

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1_"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2_"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_weight="1"
          />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_weight="1"
        />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that fixed the vertical linear layout but the other textviews are still messed up

Comment: setting the min and max width for the textviews in the vertical linear layout fixed it ty for the answer